# Loop throuh array of arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I have an array that I got from my `$_POST` data with this values

```
Array ( 
    [unit] => 
    [items] => Array ( 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [category] => 1 
            [items] => 5 
            [qty] => 1 
            [jan] => 1 
            [feb] => 
            [mar] => 
            [apr] => 
            [may] =>
            [jun] => 
            [jul] => 
            [aug] => 
            [sep] => 
            [oct] => 
            [nov] => 
            [dec] => 
        ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [category] => 1 
            [items] => 20 
            [qty] => 1 
            [jan] => 1 
            [feb] => 
            [mar] => 
            [apr] => 
            [may] => 
            [jun] => 
            [jul] => 
            [aug] => 
            [sep] => 
            [oct] => 
            [nov] => 
            [dec] => 
        ) 
        [3] => Array ( 
            [category] => 1 
            [items] => 27 
            [qty] => 1 
            [jan] => 1 
            [feb] => 
            [mar] => 
            [apr] => 
            [may] => 
            [jun] => 
            [jul] => 
            [aug] => 
            [sep] => 
            [oct] => 
            [nov] => 
            [dec] => 
        ) 
    ) 
    [action] => 
)
```

I'm trying to get each array and pass it to my model for database insertion. For example get the array of `[items]` where `[1]` points.

I have tried using

```
$array_col = array_column($_POST, 'items');
print_r($array_col);
```

but it returns `Array()` which is empty.

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your data are in `$_POST['items']`.
so:

```
$array_col = $_POST['items'];
```

Then, to iterate through them you need a `loop`.

```
foreach($array_col as $col){
  // Do your stuff here
  print_r($col);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to get each `$_POST['items']` individually. Like the `[1]` first then `[2]` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

From PHP documentation ...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php 
`array_column() returns the values from a single column of the input, identified by the column_key. Optionally, an index_key may be provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column of the input array`.

Check you have array key index - '`items`' are in various levels (level-0 and also in level 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $a){
    // Code will go here. Whatever.
    print_r($a);
}
```